# Pick every ip address but one in particular

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex which returns me every possible ip address so between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 but one in particular which is 127.0.0.1

i played a little bit with regex but they are a little bit complex
i was doing something like that but even using regex101.com im not able to obtain the proper one.

```
^(?![0-9\.]+:)(?!127.0.0.1:)
```

Comment: The lookahead needs to go ahead of the text you want to look ahead on. `^(?!127\.0\.0\.1:)[0-9.]+:`

Comment: for what it's worth,  the entire class A under 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255) is reserved as a loopback range; so while 127.0.0.1 is by far the most common local address, anything starting with 127. is a local address.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!127\.0\.0\.1)(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Should work as required

Brief explanation:

first checks that it does not contain 127.0.0.1,

followed by 3 loads of 0-255. ending with 0-255

Comment: Perfect ! thank you very much and if i'd like to do exactly the opposite ? so accepting me only 127.0.0.1 instead of everything else ?

Comment: Then you would simply need ^127\.0\.0\.1$

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted answer if it contains a solution to your problem, as it also helps others searching for the problem to find it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well and do the validation of range.

```
^(?!127.0.0.1)((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))$
```